# Single-engine plane with long range flyable in Europe

Tags: general-aviation, usa, eu

Not 100% sure if choice of airplane is on-topic here, please let me know if not.

Just got my PPL, and looking for a choice of single-engine meeting a few conditions:

- Long-range, definitely >800nm, ideally >1200nm
- Can be flown IFR with only IR (no special type/class ratings) under both FAA and EASA
- Available used for under $100K, ideally less

Are there planes out there that meet these conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely aircraft which meet some of your criteria, namely range above 800nm and can be flown IFR. I'm not going to list them all, notable examples would be the Mooney M20 series, the Cirrus SR22, Cessna 182 and Cessna 210. No doubt there are more. The issue will be cost, you can find older M20s and Cessnas for your budget, the cheaper they are the shorter time the engines have until they need a costly overhaul and the more work they'll need.

Comment: I'd generally give it more time on accepting an answer, but this one really checked all the boxes. Some classic Cessnas, the Mooney (though they just laid off all their staff, so remains to be seen whether they'll be maintainable), and the SR22, which might be a bit young to be in the right price range, but does fantastically on range, punch, and gotta love that parachute. Hard to argue with these choices right here :)

Comment: I'm glad you think it's useful @TheEnvironmentalist. Buying an airplane is one thing, maintaining it is another thing cost-wise. Unless you are flying a lot buying a share may be a better choice.

Comment: I imagine that owing a <$100k aircraft is like owning a Mercedes or BMW from the early 2000s - the price of entry is low (relatively speaking), but _oh_ the maintenance costs!!

Comment: I have one of each of those brands and they have been some of the cheapest cars to maintain @FreeMan. They just last. Well, maybe the M3 is a special case, but it's an M3!

Comment: Not wishing any ill upon you, @GdD, but I'm guessing you haven't had an electronics failure yet. Or, maybe it was from the 90s when all the electronic gee-gaws started coming in, but they weren't all that reliable yet.

Comment: Both mine are from the early 2000s @FreeMan. I had a Porsche 944 as well which was remarkably inexpensive for parts. Sadly written off when someone crashed into it in front of my house. I miss that car.